# d3 idiom for appending grouped elements on enter()?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Is there a better idiom to append a `<svg:g>` grouped set of elements to a container on an `enter()` selection as part of a generic update pattern?

```
var cell = d3.select(this); // parent container

cell = cell
  .selectAll('.plot').data([0]);   // seems kludgy

cell
  .enter().append('g').classed('plot',true);  // append the wrapping <g> element

cell = cell
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(_.values(slice));

cell
  .enter().append("circle"); // general enter() -- create plot elements

cell.attr() // etc.  general update--style plot elements

cell
  .exit().remove();
```

Of course,

```
if ( cell.select('g.plot').empty() ) {
  cell = cell.append('g').classed('plot', true);
}
```

instead of the first two statements would do it too, but this seems like a very common operation and the `selectAll().data([0])` seems contrived--is there a more elegant d3 idiom?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for here -- could you just append the `g` element before making any selection?

Comment: Agree with Lars: it feels like you're overkilling with the code. Simply append a "g" for every new group of elements that you need.

var cell = d3.select(this)
  .append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(…);

cell.enter().append("circle")
    .attr(…);

cell.exit().remove();

Comment: The point is to only append the `g` once, at the time of the first `enter()` selection. Otherwise after a few updates we'd end up with a lot of `g`s with only a subset (or none) of the child elements in each. What would be natural is `cell.selectAll('g.plot circles').enter() .append('g').classed('plot',true').append('circle')...` i.e. create the path to the target `enter()` selection if it doesn't exist. But obviously that form won't work, it would wrap each circle in its own group. So the question is is there an idiom or helper already in d3 to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating an element if necessary or selecting it otherwise, I would usually use a structure similar to your if block as opposed to using a data join with meaningless data.

Not only is it shorter code, but it means that you're not carrying around that extra data property on your element when it doesn't have any significance.  It's also easier for other people to figure out what you're doing!

The only thing I would change is to actually save the selection that you're using for the `.empty()` test, since if it's *not* empty you'll be using it.  (You could use another variable to save the this-selection, but `d3.select(this)` isn't exactly a high computation method call to repeat, and even then you'll only be repeating it once, when you first create the group.)

```
var plot = d3.select(this) // this is the parent container
             .selectAll('g.plot'); //select the plot group if it exists

if ( plot.empty() ) 
    plot = d3.select(this).append('g').classed('plot',true);
           //create the plot group if necessary

var cell = plot.selectAll("circle") //now select/create data elements as usual
  .data(_.values(slice));

cell
  .enter().append("circle"); // general enter() -- create plot elements

cell.attr() // etc.  general update--style plot elements

cell
  .exit().remove();
```

Comment: OK that's straightforward--I'll accept it unless there is a more clever/chained-styleh trick. Not trying to be fancy for the sake of it--just seems like 'create the DOM path to the enter() selection if it doesn't already exist' is a common op.

Answer (score 0):

Simply append a "g" for every new group of elements that you need.

```
var cell = d3.select(this)
  .append("g")
    .attr("class","plot")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(…);

cell.enter().append("circle")
    .attr(…);

cell.exit().remove();
```

What doesn't work here?

Comment: The question by @tribalvibes wasn't completely clear, but I think the question is how to deal with the question of "append the g element if it doesn't already exist, or select it if it does".